# Open link using Selenium on new page

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

I am clicking the link "Images" on a new page (after searching 'bugs bunny') on Google. It is not retrieving images of the search, rather it is opening the link 'Images' on the old page.

My Code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')

search = browser.find_element_by_name('q')
search.send_keys("bugs bunny")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) # hit return after you enter search text
browser.current_window_handle
print(browser.current_url)
browser.find_element_by_link_text("Images").click()
```

Comment: For me this is working fine. Try with the latest version of Firefox

Comment: It it not opening the new page with the search result!! even after upgrade to the latest firefox

Comment: Put some sleep after return and then try

Comment: Thanks it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you are using send_keys, which perform the action and don't wait

```
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) # hit return after you enter search text
```

So after that if you use `click` it is doing it nearly on the current page even when the results are not loaded. So you need to add some delay for the return key to change the results and once the results are loaded, you can do the click

So what you need is a simple `sleep` delay